# Vue Jest Nested Components

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs

I am working on a Vue Application which has nested components.

I am using Jest for writing Unit test cases.

While executing unit test cases on a parent component, i noticed the child components are not loaded.

I am using shallow rendering in test suites.

Please share any links or tutorials on this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Use `mount` instead of `shallow`

b) Import the child component at the top of the `spec.js` file, just as you did with the parent